# Tail call for pipelined functions

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have some pipelined function:

```
create type my_tab_type as table of ...

create function my_func (X in number) return my_tab_type pipelined as
begin
  loop
    ...
    pipe row (...);
  end loop;
  return;
end;
```

Now I want to create another pipelined function `my_func_zero` which does the same as `my_func` but for fixed value of parameter: `my_func_zero` must be equivalent to `my_func(0)`.

Can I implement `my_func_zero` without senseless and boring loop for processing every row returned by `select * from table(my_func(0))`?

P.S. [That](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2779495/1847592) thread is a bit similar, but it does not contain answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but only if you don't declare your second function as `pipelined` because all functions of this type return results on row-by-row basis.

If you omit this requirement you can reach your target with bulk collect if you need typed cursor:

```
create function my_zero_func return my_tab_type
as
  res_table my_tab_type;
begin

  select my_type(field1, field2)
  bulk collect into res_table
  from table(my_func(0));

  return res_table;

end;
```

Alternatively you can use untyped cursor:

```
create function my_ref_zero_func return sys_refcursor
as
  vRes sys_refcursor;
begin

  open vRes for select * from table(my_func(0));

  return vRes;

end;
```

[<kbd>SQLFiddle</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/66570/3)

In a client application `my_ref_zero_func` results may be used without changes, but in the SQLFiddle it converted to XML representation because there are no way to demonstrate `ref cursor` with this tool.